# Angular4: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined while accessing length property

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material

i'am working on a assignment of angular 4, i'am new to it, i'am applying pagination for mat-table,getting some problem in it,   while i'am printing data to console it is displaying as below [image]

while i'am trying to apply dataSource.data.length, getting below error.

```
WellComponent.html:57 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.View_WellComponent_0._co [as updateDirectives] (WellComponent.html:60)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13075)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12255)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12620)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12552)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12261)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12620)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12578)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12256)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12620)
```

Can i get help in this aspect, how should i access that length property.

**Component:**

```
    import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';
    import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
    import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild,ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { WellService } from '../services/well.service';
    import { Well } from '../well/well';
    import {  Observable  } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { BehaviorSubject } from  'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



    @Component({
      selector: 'app-well',
      templateUrl: './well.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./well.component.css'],
      providers:[WellService]
    })



    export class WellComponent implements OnInit {
      title = 'Wells';
      header:string;  
      displayedColumns = ['active', 'company', 'country', 'well','wellbore'];
      public dataSource: WellDataSource | any;
      obs:any;

      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator : MatPaginator;

      constructor(private wellService:WellService) {

        this.header='assets/images/BHI_header_logo_bd.png'  

       }

       ngOnInit() {
        this.obs = this.wellService.getWells();
        this.dataSource = new WellDataSource(this.obs, this.paginator);

      }

      }

      export class WellDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

      constructor(private _obs: any, private _paginator: MatPaginator) {
        super();
      }

      connect(): Observable<any[]> {
        const displayDataChanges = [
          this._obs,
          this._paginator.page,
        ];

        return this._obs.flatMap(x => {
          return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
            const data = x.slice();
            console.log(data);
            const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
            console.log(startIndex);
            console.log(this._paginator.pageSize)
            console.log(this._obs);
            console.log(x.slice());
            return data.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
          });
        })
      }

        disconnect() {}
      }


**HTML:**

<div>
  <div class="image"><img  [src]="header" ></div>

  <div class="w3-display-left">
  <nav>
     <li><a routerLink="/wells" routerLinkActive="active">My Wells</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="/dev" routerLinkActive="active">Well Management</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="/dev" routerLinkActive="active">Admin Tools</a></li>
  </nav>
  <div class="w3-display-right">
    <button mat-button>Reset</button>
    <button mat-button>Refresh</button>
    <button mat-button>View Wireline</button>
    <button mat-button>Chat</button>
    <button mat-button>View Seismic</button>
    <button mat-button>Alerts</button>

  </div>


  <br>
  <br>
   <div> 
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <!-- Active -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="active">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Active </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.active}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Company -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Company </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.company}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Country -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="country">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Country</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.country}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Well -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="well">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Well </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.well}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


        <!-- Wellbore -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="wellbore">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Wellbore </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.wellbore}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
  <mat-paginator #paginator
  [length]="dataSource.data.length"
  [pageIndex]="0"
  [pageSize]="25"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
</div>
</div> 
<div>    
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

Comment: post you code also

Comment: do you mean my component and html?

Comment: yeah right then will be able to help you

Comment: i have added them there you can check now

Answer (score 8):

The error is because of you are trying to access data before it available

Try to use safe operator :

```
dataSource.data?.length
```

OR

make some initialisation inside constructor

```
dataSource.data = [];
```

---

As per your code change `[length]="dataSource.data.length"` to  `[length]="obs.data?.length"` , like this :

```
<mat-paginator #paginator
  [length]="obs.data?.length"
  [pageIndex]="0"
  [pageSize]="25"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

Comment: tried the first condition the error is gone but pagination is not coming as expected, it is displaying 1-25 of 0, only first page.

Comment: @SaiCharan, that must be because of some other part of coding, it would be better if you can create a plunkr of the issue, this way more developers can help you and very quicly, ,will you please accept and upvote the answer ?

Comment: ya sure i will try to create the plunker

Comment: @SaiCharan, please check my updated answer and that might solve your other issue

Comment: @SaiCharan, then you have to create a plunkr for this

Comment: Yes,i'am doing now

Comment: still working it, @SaiCharan? :-D I'm dying here... can't wait to see this resolved. Appreciate the pointers, but I had the same problem. Errors went away, but display was blank. Right now I've hacked a timer to go to the next page, then back to the first page. That works, but I'm not proud of it. Does anyone have a solution for this yet?

Comment: make some initialisation inside constructor

dataSource.data = [];

It worked for me. Thanks@VivekDoshi

Answer (score 1):

Initializing the array caused the errors to go away but the data in the table would never get updated-- it was blank. Adding the question mark (i.e. dataSource.data?.length) didnt work because there were other places where it was expected to not be undefined.

Some kid told me to try a BehaviorSubject. They are an Observable that always has a value. When you subscribe you get the latest value. They are also Observers and you can tell them what the next value is. Read more here.

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject

I made dataSource.data a BehaviorSubject, way the kid told me to, with initial value [] then told it (via next()) when the value changed.

And, because I am doing sorting and pagination I had to update that code to use this.data.getValue() instead of this.data.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by combining two approaches:

a) Safe operator

> [length]="dataSource.data?.length"

b) correctly initializing the datasource (avoid slice error)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource = new EmplTblDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort);
  this.dataSource.data=[];
}
```

Then, I update the table content in `OnChanges` method